# Bison loop for conflict

Tags: c, if-statement, bison, flex-lexer

to solve the dangling else problem, I used the following solution:

```
stmt            : stmt_matched
                | stmt_unmatched
                ;
stmt_unmatched  : IF '(' exp ')' stmt
                | IF '(' exp ')' stmt_matched ELSE stmt_unmatched
                ;
stmt_matched    : IF '(' exp ')' stmt_matched ELSE stmt_matched
                | stmt_for
                | ...
                ;
```

For defining the rules of grammar about the for loop, I produce a conflict shift/reduce due to the same problem:

```
stmt_for        : FOR '(' exp ';' exp ';' exp ')' stmt
            ;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all `for` statements are matched. Consider, for example

```
 if (c) for (;;) if (d) ; else ;
```

So it is necessary to divide `for` statements into `for_matched` and `for_unmatched`. (And similarly with other compound statements such as `while`.)

Comment: So I have to add the for_matched in stmt matched and for_unmatched in stmt unmatched?
Accordingly
stmt_for_matched : FOR '(' exp ';' exp ';' exp ')' stmt_matched 
       ;and 
stmt_for_unmatched : FOR '(' exp ';' exp ';' exp ')' stmt_unmatched 
       ;