# Parsing nested `if/else' statements

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, earley-parser, nearley

I am working on a JavaScript implementation of the `OpenSCAD` language, which -- for this purpose -- is a C-type language.

I've been able to successfully parse all sorts of `if` and `if/else` statements:

```
if(true) t1=200;t2=500;
if(true) t1=200;
if(true)t1=200;
if(true){t1=200;}
if(true) if(false) {t1=200;}
if(true){t1=200;} else {t2=500;}
```

However, I have come across a particular combo that is leaving me with 'ambiguous grammar' -- `Nearley.js`'s way of saying the parsing may happen in multiple ways:

```
if(true) if(false) {t1=200;} else {echo("hi");}
```

*Attempted solution 1:  Crafted from a handful of different sources*

```
selection_statement
    -> elseIfStatement {% id %}


bareifStatement
    -> "if" _ "(" _ expression _ ")" _ statement  {% d => d %}

elseIfStatement
    -> bareifStatement _ "else" _ statement {% ifstatement %}
    | bareifStatement _ elseIfStatement {% id %}
    | bareifStatement
```

*Attempted Solution #2*
Culled from https://github.com/vsl-lang/VSL/blob/develop/src/vsl/parser/parser.ne

```
IfStatement
   -> "if" _ "(" _ expression _ ")" _ statement (
        _ "else" _ (
            statement {% id %}
        ) {% debug %}
    ):? {% debug %}
```

*Attempted Solution 3: Still can parse two ways*

```
selection_statement
    -> elseIfStatement {% id %}

elseIfStatement
    -> "if" _ "(" _ expression _ ")" _ statement  (_ "else" _ statement):? {% ifstatement %}
```

Has anyone successfully parsed this kind of grammar in an Earley syntax?

Hints? Suggestions?  Heck, I'll even take a solution!

(The entire package is available on github, but it will require a few tweaks before it can run on other machines.)  https://github.com/JeremyJStarcher/openscadtojs

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088400/bison-loop-for-conflict  If not, there are dozens of other ones. Search for "dangling else". (I don't know where you got solution 1 from, but it is certainly not correct.)

Comment: "dangling else" -- Hmmm.. that's a term I've not heard.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the magic phrase I needed.  Several hours of research later took me to this page, which laid out the pieces in the order I need.  https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/G22.2130-001/grammar.html

Comment: cool. That's the solution in the SO question/answer I linked; was it not obvious enough in that answer?

Comment: @rici Yes, the same solution but -- I'm still learning how to write grammar. The answer I linked to provided a little bit more context on where to put the pieces.

Comment: @jeremt: ok, i'll work on it tomorrow.